# Blackberry: Twitter LoginWebPage content not Display in English

Tags: http, blackberry

In My Blackberry Twitter Integration In LogingPage Some Context( Text etc) not Show in English is show garbage May be Its show like other Language which not support Devise so garbage Text Show according to me i am not sure. So please if any idea please answer me

i also Modify the Code for Request where Post

```
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

//conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

conn.setRequestProperty(
    "Content-Type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty(
    "Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length));

OutputStream out = conn.openOutputStream();
out.write(postData);
out.close();
```

Comment: close the wifi and try to get with mobile data then you should get it

Comment: Try my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091900/twitter-integration-in-blackberry-login-page-not-in-english

Answer (score 0):

Try with BIS. It works fine with BIS. Else you can call HTTP GET and POST methode to the following urls.

For request token call https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token (HTTP GET with key , secret, and signature).Then you will get the request token

For Authorization call this link in your browser https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=your request token

For access token call https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token (HTTP POST with key , secret, signature , token) . Then you will get the access token and secret.