# Twitter Integration in Blackberry: Login Page not in English

Tags: blackberry, twitter, browserfield

I am trying to integrate twitter using [Twitter Api me 1.8](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads) . When i try to authorize using  OAuth the login Screen look like below .Some invalid charecters are showing.please help me to identify the problem

thanks

[image]

Comment: What language are you using, please express what is your local language , as this seems to be character are you seeing are not on device and device fails to decode characters.

Comment: Device language set to the US-English.

Comment: hi @Ajmal i m also facing this problem in API 1.8 ..i tried alot ..but can get solution yet ...

Comment: @coder i m not solve the problem yet.

Comment: @Ajmal i had tried alot to solve this problem ... try localization and set header forcefully in enfglish but ..not solve yet ..

Comment: @Coder will you get any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Ajmal not yet ..my app is for US and it is working properly there in english . we are in india so we are getting this result . if your app is only for US than dont worry its works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the login page content is not displayed properly in BlackBerry, then follow this link.

Please, use BrowserFieldOAuthDialogWrapper in place of BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper class. It works fine for me.
    http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/forums/forum/topics/523812-A-test-for-invalid-characters-on-Blackberry#p571144

I got this success by the help of @ernandesmjr Ernandes Mourao Jr

If any find any issue. please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Try with BIS. It works fine with BIS. Else you can call HTTP GET and POST methode to the following urls.

For request token call  https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token (HTTP GET with key , secret, and signature).Then you will get the request token

For Authorization call this link in your browser https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=your request token

For access token call https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token (HTTP POST with key , secret, signature , token) . Then you will get the access token and secret.